# MySQL query posts by tag

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to search for all posts for a specific tag name, whilst still being able to join all tags for the returned posts.

#### posts

id
...

#### tags

id
name
slug

#### posts_tags

id
post_id
tag_id

I'll do a query such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.d
WHERE t.slug = 'foo'
```

This will return me all posts with the tag `foo`, but will no longer join the other tags associated with the posts. How can I write it in such a way so I can still get all tags on the posts?

For example, say I have a post which has 3 tags associated with it: `cat`, `dog` and `chimp`. I want to do a query for posts which have the tag `dog`. How can I construct a query which will fetch me the posts with the tag `dog`, ensuring that the `cat` and `chimp` tags are also retrieved in the result?

Comment: How should the result look like? Please post a result set example.

Comment: Was the question not self explanatory?

Comment: Don't you see all the different answers? So no - it's not self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the tags for all the posts which include `foo` as well as all other tags, then i think you can do a left join.

```
SELECT * FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN tags t 
ON pt.tag_id = t.d
```

Above will give you all the posts and the relevant tags for the posts. You can `order by slug` OR you can add a clause with left join to filter by tag you need like below:

```
    SELECT * FROM posts p 
    INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN tags t 
    ON pt.tag_id = t.d AND t.slug IN ('foo') --add other tags if needed
```

Comment: The `IN` clause seems to make no difference to the query, all rows are always returned.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  all the tags slug related  to post that are related  to foo  then you could use

```
select distinct tags.slug 
from tags 
inner join (
    SELECT post_id  from posts_tags pt 
    INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.d
    WHERE t.slug = 'foo' 
    ) t on t.id = post_tags.post_id
inner join tags on tags.id = post_tags.tag_id
```

or if you need  the related  post too

```
select post.*, tags.slug 
from tags 
inner join (
    SELECT post_id  from posts_tags pt 
    INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.d
    WHERE t.slug = 'foo' 
    ) t on t.id = post_tags.post_id
inner join tags on tags.id = post_tags.tag_id 
inner join post on post.id = post_tag.post_id
```

Comment: You don't need the `posts` table for this result.

Comment: You would need the posts table since I want to join tags to the posts... not fetch *only* tags from the post. I'll update the question incase it wasn't clear already.

Comment: the query in my answer  retriev the distinct tags related   ..you can add a join to this query with post for get the post  too ... anway answer  updated

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm curious to why you've chosen to select from `tags`, wouldn't it make more sense to select from `posts` and join the `posts` table?

Comment: if you look at the two query you see  that the second is the one with a simple adding of join to  post ... my second query is for suggest you that once you have the first the second come natural .. .Once you have a working query that work right  then you can change the order  of inner for see the best performance  ... using explain plan ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the posts that have 'foo' as a tag, then you need more complicated logic.  For your purposes, I think it is probably sufficient to get the tags as a delimited list:

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.slug) as tags
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     posts_tags pt
     ON pt.post_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     tags t
     ON pt.tag_id = t.d
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(t.slug = 'foo') > 0;
```

Comment: I don't want them in a list as I also want the other columns in the tags table.